# argparse: handle version string like help string

Tags: python, argparse

I am using Python 3.6 with argparse 1.1.

Besides `-h`/`--help` I want to have an option `-v`/`--version` that prints a string with version information and quits the program (like with the help string). However when I also have positional arguments, executing

```
$ example --version
```

results in

```
usage: example ... 
error: too few arguments
```

### Work around solution

I have a work around solution, which I don't like as I need quite some lines of code to do something that argparse could do much better.

```
import sys,argparse

class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def format_help(self):
        return 'Help string\n'

def printversion():
    print('0.0.1')
    sys.exit(1)

if len(sys.argv)>1:
    if len(sys.argv[1])>0:
        if sys.argv[1] in ['--version']:
            printversion()

parser = MyParser()
parser.add_argument('argument',nargs=1,type=int)
parser.add_argument('-v','--version',action='store_true')

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['version']: printversion()
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `docopt` is a way better then anything else. It should help to avoid silly mistakes. http://docopt.org

Comment: @Igor Seems awesome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`argparse` already has [a `version` action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) for exactly this:

> `'version'` - This expects a `version=` keyword argument in the `add_argument()` call, and prints version information and exits when invoked:
>
> ```
> >>> import argparse
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
> >>> parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 2.0')
> >>> parser.parse_args(['--version'])
> PROG 2.0
> ```

Comment: Great, I guess I misread / misjudged this part of the help. In fact, I want to supply a multi-line string `'hello\nworld'`. It seems to ignore the line-break. Can I avoid that?

Comment: Look at the code for `argparse._VersionAction`.  It uses the `HelpFormater`.  So using one of the `RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` or `RawTextHelpFormatter` might preserve newlines.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue9399 asks for a generalized `print` action, that would handle longer texts.  `version` was designed for simple version number display, and isn't widely used anymore.